# Gravando endereços IP em arquivo, cada IP em uma linha diferente usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
from scapy.all import *


pkts = rdpcap("lalalao.pcap")

for p in pkts:
##  print p.time


        if IP in p: #if packet has IP layer
                    src_ip = p[IP].src
                    dest_ip = p[IP].dst
                    print src_ip

                    f = open('IP_src.txt', 'a+')
                    for ip in src_ip:
                            f.writelines(ip)

                    f.close()
```

O código acima imprime corretamente src_ip um por linha:

```
216.58.202.229
216.58.202.229
192.168.1.3
216.58.202.229
216.58.202.229
192.168.1.3
216.58.202.229
216.58.202.229
192.168.1.3
216.58.202.229
192.168.1.3
216.58.202.229
```

Mas na hora de salvar no arquivo IP_src.txt, o arquivo fica todo bagunçado , tudo na mesma linha. Como salvar o src_ip no arquivo um por linha?
Quando eu passar este arquivo para outro programa ler, dá alguma problema os src_ip estarem um por linha? Existe diferença entre o python 2 e python 3 neste ponto?

Comment: f.write('{}\n'.format(ip)), tenta isso Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou inserir a quebra de linha "\n", vc pode utilizar `.write("\n")` por exemplo:

```
from scapy.all import *


pkts = rdpcap("lalalao.pcap")

for p in pkts:
    ##  print p.time


    if IP in p: #if packet has IP layer
        src_ip = p[IP].src
        dest_ip = p[IP].dst
        print src_ip

        f = open('IP_src.txt', 'w')
        for ip in src_ip:
            f.write(ip + "\n")

        f.close()
```

Comment: ,Quando eu passar este arquivo para outro programa ler, dá alguma problema os src_ip estarem um por linha?

Comment: writelines() nao funciona?

Comment: o codigo aqui nao funcionou... Os IPs foram salvos na vertical:   http://imgur.com/a/97bGW

Comment: Provavelmente não irá ter problema para leitura de outro programa, na verdade o unico problema que pode ocorrer é de encode, mais acredito que tbm não irá acontecer. Com relaçao ao codigo, tenta fazer `f.writelines(ip)` e logo em seguida `f.write("\n")`

Comment: Se mesmo assim ele continuar quebrando todo o ip por caracter, vc vai precisar colocar o ´f.write("\n")´ só quando ele terminar o `for ip in src_ip:`

Comment: só funcionou com: "Se mesmo assim ele continuar quebrando todo o ip por caracter, vc vai precisar colocar o ´f.write("\n")´ só quando ele terminar o for ip in src_ip".

Comment: obrigado. Como fazer para que o arquivo seja "zerado"/limpo a cada vez que o programa rodar?

Comment: a sim, fiquei com duvida se ele estava vindo o array de caracteres do ip ou um array de ips

Comment: para limpar o arquivo e sobrescrever vc precisa definir `w` na leitura `f = open('IP_src.txt',  'w')`

Comment: A resposta está errada. 'Writelines" espera uma sequência - se você passar uma string, é uma chamada apropriada para escrever várias linhas que já estejam preparadas (com "\n" no final) em uma lista.
Como o Python interage strings puxando um caractere por vez, esse erro pode passar despercebido - mas você estará fazendo internamente muito mais chamadas ao sistema do que o necessário.  

Troque o `f.writelines(ip)`  por `f.write(ip + "\n")`  (pronto, a quebra de linha já é inserida junto com o ip)  - E, ao arrumar isso, aproveite e arrume a identação.